# Microsoft Graph API authentication error(Error Description: /me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, aspose

We have a console application that uses Aspose email dll for sending mails and various other functionalities.

Since it uses basic authentication that is getting deprecated soon by microsoft so we are planning to have authentication using Microsoft Graph API.

So I have done below steps

1)Registered the app in Microsoft Azure active directory and gave permissions under Microsoft Graph. PFA(AzureAPP_permissions.png)

2)I added code for generating token using graph API and then tried fetching email,sending email using Aspose dll but every time it throws below error.

**Aspose.Email.AsposeBadServerResponceException: 'Server error Status: BadRequest
Description: /me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.
Details:

> > > 

POST: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages
---------------------------------------**
Please help what is going wrong here
PFB the code part

### Graph_code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Aspose.Email.Clients;
using Aspose.Email.Clients.Graph;
using Aspose.Email.Mapi;
using EASendMail;

namespace Email
{
    internal class Graph_API
    {
        private static string _clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
        private static string _tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TenantId"];
        private static string _secretValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecretValue"];
        
        static string _postString(string uri, string requestData)
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
            httpRequest.Method = "POST";
           httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
          
            

            using (Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                byte[] requestBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData);
                requestStream.Write(requestBuffer, 0, requestBuffer.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
            }

            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                var responseText = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(responseText);
                return responseText;
               
            }
            catch (WebException ep)
            {
                if (ep.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                {
                    var responseText = new StreamReader(ep.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(responseText);
                }

                throw ep;
            }
        }

        public string GenerateToken()
          {
            
                string client_id = _clientId;
                string client_secret = _secretValue;

               
                string tenant = _tenantId;

                  
                          


                string requestData =
                string.Format("client_id={0}&client_secret={1}" + "&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&grant_type=client_credentials",
                client_id, client_secret);

                string tokenUri = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token", tenant);
               
               
                string responseText = _postString(tokenUri, requestData);

                OAuthResponseParser parser = new OAuthResponseParser();
                parser.Load(responseText);

            
            var vv = parser.AccessToken;
            return vv;

           
           
        }




        public void Generatemail()

        {

            interface_class bb = new interface_class();
            IGraphClient client = GraphClient.GetClient(bb, _tenantId);
            MapiMessage mm = new MapiMessage();
            mm.Subject = "EMAILNET-39318 " + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            mm.Body = "EMAILNET-39318 REST API v1.0 - Create Message";
            mm.SetProperty(KnownPropertyList.DisplayTo, "xxx@outlook.com");
            mm.SetProperty(KnownPropertyList.SenderName, "xxx@outlook.com");
            mm.SetProperty(KnownPropertyList.SentRepresentingEmailAddress, "xxx@outlook.com");

            // Create message in inbox folder
            MapiMessage createdMessage = client.CreateMessage(Aspose.Email.Clients.Graph.KnownFolders.Inbox, mm);

        }

        public void FetchMail()
        {
            try
            {
                interface_class bb = new interface_class();
               
                using (IGraphClient client = GraphClient.GetClient(bb, _tenantId))
                {
                    FolderInfoCollection folderInfoCol1 = client.ListFolders();
                    FolderInfo inbox = null;
                    foreach (FolderInfo folderInfo in folderInfoCol1)
                    {
                        if (folderInfo.DisplayName.Equals("Inbox", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            inbox = folderInfo;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    MessageInfoCollection messageInfoCol = client.ListMessages(inbox.ItemId);
                    MessageInfo messageInfo = messageInfoCol[0];
                    MapiMessage message = client.FetchMessage(messageInfo.ItemId);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            }

        }
    }
```

---

### Itokenimplementor_class code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Aspose.Email.Clients;
using Aspose.Email.Clients.Graph;

namespace Email
{
    internal class interface_class : ITokenProvider
    {
        Graph_API obj = new Graph_API();
        DateTime expirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public OAuthToken GetAccessToken()
        {
            string token = obj.GenerateToken();

            return new OAuthToken(token, expirationDate);
        }

        public OAuthToken GetAccessToken(bool ignoreExistingToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Did my post work for you?

Comment: Could you please try the latest version of [Aspose.Email for .NET 22.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Email/22.9.0) and let us know how it goes on your side?

Answer (score 1):

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages` This endpoint is used to query inbox messages for a user right? Then who is `/me` here? And this is the issue.

In your code snippet, I noticed that you set the `grant_type=client_credentials` so you are using client credential flow. It's correct but pls note that you need to give application api permission. Application api permission is for client credential flow. And [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) require `Mail.ReadBasic.All, Mail.Read, Mail.ReadWrite` permissions.

[image]

If you can generate access token successfully, you may [decode the token](https://jwt.io/) the check if the `roles` claim contained correct permissions.

When you get a correct token, then pls use `Get:  /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/mailFolders/inbox/messages` instead of `/me`. If you want to query emails for `user1@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com`, then the url can be `/users/user1@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/mailFolders/inbox/messages`.

I also notice that you had `GraphClient` in your code. So you may also try my code below:

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "your_tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "azure_ad_app_client_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret_for_the_azuread_app";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var messages = await graphClient.Users["user_id/PrincipalName"].Messages
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I used url like below:  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxxoutlook.onmicrosoft.com/mailFolders/inbox/messages
--------------But now I am getting new error as below.....................................Aspose.Email.AsposeBadServerResponceException: 'Server error Status: ResourceNotFound
   Description: Resource could not be discovered.
   Details:
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Comment: it seems to be anothor question... `Aspose.Email.AsposeBadServerResponceException` thrown by `Aspose`?  So did you get the message query result? You were trying to query messages via graph api, so the error message shouldn't relate to `Aspose`. You can add a break point to check if you get the query result. If not, pls check if the account `xxxoutlook.onmicrosoft.com` existed in your tenant, if not, pls use a member account for testing. If you can get the query result, then the issue now is related to Aspose.