# Receiving error while fetching mails using Aspose Email dll and Microsoft Graph Client API

Tags: authentication, email, microsoft-graph-api, c#-3.0, aspose

Below is the code part along with error being received

### Error received

Aspose.Email.AsposeBadServerResponceException: 'Server error Status: ResourceNotFound
Description: Resource could not be discovered.
Details:

> > > 

GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/1234outlook.onmicrosoft.com/mailFolders

### Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx
Accept: application/json

### Code 1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Aspose.Email.Clients;
using Aspose.Email.Clients.Graph;
using Aspose.Email.Mapi;
using Azure.Identity;
using EASendMail;
using Microsoft.Graph;

namespace Code
{
    internal class Graph_API
    {
        private static string _clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
        private static string _tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TenantId"];
        private static string _secretValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecretValue"];
        
        static string _postString(string uri, string requestData)
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
            httpRequest.Method = "POST";
           httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
          
            

            using (Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                byte[] requestBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData);
                requestStream.Write(requestBuffer, 0, requestBuffer.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
            }

            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                var responseText = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(responseText);
                return responseText;
               
            }
            catch (WebException ep)
            {
                if (ep.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                {
                    var responseText = new StreamReader(ep.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(responseText);
                }

                throw ep;
            }
        }

        public string GenerateToken()
          {
            
                string client_id = _clientId;
                string client_secret = _secretValue;

               
                string tenant = _tenantId;


            string requestData =
                string.Format("client_id={0}&client_secret={1}" +
                "&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&grant_type=client_credentials",
                client_id, client_secret);

            string tokenUri = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token", tenant);

            
            string responseText = _postString(tokenUri, requestData);

                OAuthResponseParser parser = new OAuthResponseParser();
                parser.Load(responseText);

            
            var vv = parser.AccessToken;
            return vv;

           
           
        }




        public void Generatemail()

        {

            interface_class bb = new interface_class();
            IGraphClient client = GraphClient.GetClient(bb, _tenantId);
            client.Resource = (ResourceType)1;
            client.ResourceId = "1234outlook.onmicrosoft.com";
            MapiMessage mm = new MapiMessage();
            mm.Subject = "EMAILNET-39318 " + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            mm.Body = "EMAILNET-39318 REST API v1.0 - Create Message";
            mm.SetProperty(KnownPropertyList.DisplayTo, "1234outlook.onmicrosoft.com");
            mm.SetProperty(KnownPropertyList.SenderName, "1234outlook.onmicrosoft.com");
            mm.SetProperty(KnownPropertyList.SentRepresentingEmailAddress, "1234outlook.onmicrosoft.com");

            // Create message in inbox folder
            MapiMessage createdMessage = client.CreateMessage(Aspose.Email.Clients.Graph.KnownFolders.Inbox, mm);

        }

        public void  FetchMail()
        {
            try
            {
                interface_class bb = new interface_class();
                
                using (IGraphClient client = GraphClient.GetClient(bb, _tenantId))
                {
                    client.Resource = (ResourceType)1;
                    client.ResourceId = "1234outlook.onmicrosoft.com";

                   FolderInfoCollection folderInfoCol1 = client.ListFolders();

                        FolderInfo inbox = null;
                    foreach (FolderInfo folderInfo in folderInfoCol1)
                    {
                        if (folderInfo.DisplayName.Equals("Inbox", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            inbox = folderInfo;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    MessageInfoCollection messageInfoCol = client.ListMessages(inbox.ItemId);
                    MessageInfo messageInfo = messageInfoCol[0];
                    MapiMessage message = client.FetchMessage(messageInfo.ItemId);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            }

        }
    }


--------------
```

### Code file 2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Aspose.Email.Clients;
using Aspose.Email.Clients.Graph;

namespace Code
{
    internal class interface_class : ITokenProvider
    {
        Graph_API obj = new Graph_API();
        DateTime expirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public OAuthToken GetAccessToken()
        {
            string token = obj.GenerateToken();

            return new OAuthToken(token, expirationDate);
        }

        public OAuthToken GetAccessToken(bool ignoreExistingToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Comment: same question with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73892229/microsoft-graph-api-authentication-errorerror-description-me-request-is-only/73893098)? Could you pls let me know if you are using an asp.net core application?

Comment: No not using core just .net framework 4.8

Comment: Could you please try the latest version of [Aspose.Email for .NET 22.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Email/22.9.0) and let us know how it goes on your side?